# MySQL replcating huge changing data

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, large-data

Hi I have a master MySQL server with 950 gb of data and slave has stopped for some reason and there is a difference of 80gb of data.
so I started to setup new slave .

Since the data is changing and multiple databases dumping, copying  and restoring will take  lot of time .
So do I have any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Do not panic.  The size (on disk) of a table (or the entire database) is not likely to be identical between Primary and Replica.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` will give you the exact number of rows (at the time that query started); run that on both servers.  If they are the same (or close), I declare a "false alarm".  If different, we need more details to help you.

dba.stackexchange.com would be a better forum for MySQL administration questions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue,

Here are some challenges I faced and resolved.

1. slave replication stopped (only the master was handling everything R&W)
2. Master server is private and cannot be accessible to the public( master and slave are in private clouds)
3. cannot take a dump and restore because the single table was around 300GB (because MySQL stores the tables in /tmp/shm/  before restoring .which in my case was only 80GB)
4. master-slave servers don't have an active internet connection .( not able to install any packages.

And here's how I resolved it .

1 . tried adding routes to install packages. ( to install NFS -utils and percona xtrabackup )

2. only slave got an internet connection. master was still blocked .
3. installed packages in slave ( installed all packages in master manually around 35 packages )

4 created NFS in slave in / directory and mounted to master

5 performed percona xtrabackup and took backup in mounted folder in master .

6 moved the folder to /var/lib/mysql after backup and started mysql .

working fine.

If your data is changing always and large. Always percona xtrabackup should be your first choice .

Below is the doucument i followed for percona setup
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/backup_scenarios/full_backup.html